# Prove/disprove if $f:R \to R$ is continuous and $U\subset R$ is open, then $f(U)\subset R$ is open

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

**Given $f:X\to Y$ is a function and $U \subset X$, the image of $U$ under $f$ is $f(U)=\{y\in Y: y = f(x)$ for some $x\in U\}$
Prove/disprove if $f:R \to R$ is continuous and $U\subset R$ is open, then $f(U)\subset R$ is open**

I mean this intuitively makes sense. If there's an open set of U, then any function that is done upon the elements of U must also be open as well. But I don't know any direction I could go from here. I saw [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3994350/prove-f-mathbbr-to-mathbbr-is-continuous-iff-for-every-open-set-u-su) which is kind of similar but doesn't answer my question and [this was a failed proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2777027/prove-that-if-w-is-an-open-subset-of-y-then-the-set-x-in-x-fx-in-w). Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you considered a function like $y=\cos(x)$ on $(-\pi/2,5\pi/2)?$

Comment: or even more simply, $f(x)=x^2$?

Comment: or yet more simply, a constant function such as $f(x) \equiv 0$

Comment: This property is akin to having (A suitably restricted if f is not a bijection) the inverse being continuous, and thus the function being called a homeomorphism

Comment: What is $R$? The reals?

Comment: This is a duplicate question ... see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1519620/145325 the answers point to counterexamples for the case when the domain and range is the set of reals